# Swapping data in Google App-Engine datastore not taking effect

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I have an app engine datastore entity with a list of strings as a field. Each string in the list represents image urls. Needing to swap the location of two images in the list, I perform the swap in Java and then persisted the entity anew. But the swap is not reflected in the datastore. Why is that? Here is the code

```
            System.out.println("The swap is happening!”);
            Kitten p = kittenDao.getById(Long.parseLong(kittenId));
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>(p.getImgUrls());
            System.out.println("Old list: " + p.getImgUrls());
            Collections.swap(imageUrls, 0, 2);
            p.setImgUrls(new LinkedHashSet<String>(imageUrls));
            System.out.println("New list: " + p.getImgUrls());

            ArrayList<BlobKey> blobkeys = new ArrayList<BlobKey>(p.getImageKeys());
            Collections.swap(blobkeys, 0, 2);

            p.setImageKeys(new LinkedHashSet<BlobKey>(blobkeys));
            KittenDao.update(p);
            System.out.println("Updated the kitten named: " + p.getName());
```

I have been working with this server for about a year now. And all the methods behave fine. The specific problem here is the swap. Is it a known fact that App-Engine does not allow swapping list elements, when the list is a simple field?

Note that when I do `System.out.println` the new list shows the data as swapped. But the call is update ignores the swap.

Comment: I wish I could do it manually, but lists are not editable through `Datastore Viewer`

Comment: The log says what about the object state? NucleusJDOHelper.isDirty(...) tells you what about the object state? JDOHelper.makeDirty(...) can be used to force a field to be considered "dirty" (changed)

Comment: I have never used `isDirty` and `makeDirty` before. Is it a complicated thing to do, might you show an example of how that is done? My update method is essentially `mgr.merge(object);` inside a try-catch.